# Nodejs: response.write() for https.request?

Tags: node.js

Hi I am trying to make an `https.request` to an API server. I can receive the chunk and print it in the console. How can I write it directly into html and show it in the browser?

I tried to look for the equivalent of `response.write()` of `http.request` but didn't find one. `res.write(chunk)` will give me a `TypeError`. How can I do this?

```
var req = https.request(options_places, function(res){

  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function(chunk){
       console.log('BODY: ' + chunk); // Console can show chunk data
       res.write(chunk); // This gives TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'write'
  });

});

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e){
  console.log('ERROR?: ' + e.message );
});
```

Comment: You want to "*write it directly into html and show it in the browser*" -- is the browser expecting a response? Is this code inside of a function that is handling a request from the client? Otherwise, the client isn't currently making a request, and there's no way to just give content to a client that hasn't asked for it.

Comment: You'll need to [create an `http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) to [obtain a separate response object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) that you can write data to and send to the client. With `http.request()`, the script is the HTTP client, not a server. It's receiving the response another server rather than creating it.

Comment: This code runs by Node. Node.js connects to another server, sends data and receives data. Node.js doesn't even know about browser.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks. You know exactly where I was wrong at. Following the idea, I tried put the above code into `app.get()` of `express.js` and could `res.write()` the received data  in to the html and display in the browser.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks. I got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){ // Browser's GET request

  var options = {
       hostname: 'foo',
       path: 'bar',
       method: 'GET'
    };

  var clientRequest = https.request(options, function(clientResponse){

    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    clientResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
    clientResponse.on('data', function(chunk){
         console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
         res.write(chunk); // This respond to browser's GET request and write the data into html.
     });
  });

 clientRequest.end();

 clientRequest.on('error', function(e){
    console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message );
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

First you have to create server and listen on some port for the requests.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Whatever you wish to send \n');
}).listen(3000); // any free port no.
console.log('Server started');
```

Now it listens incoming connections at 127.0.0.1:3000

For specific url use .listen(3000,'your url') instead of listen(3000)